# URL RewriteRule not working. My URL appending to itself with each form submission

Tags: php, forms, mod-rewrite

I have a main url:

```
http://localhost/alias
```

I have a RewriteRule

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And have this form:

```
<form name="quick-search-form" action="test/action" method="POST">
```

Whenever I hit submit it keeps putting, one level more each time (there is not test/action, btw.  It was for testing the form tag to if it went back to index.php?url=).

```
http://localhost/alias/id/
http://localhost/alias/test/action/id
http://localhost/alias/test/action/test/action/id
```

....

Changing to GET gives me (after several times):

```
http://localhost/alias/test/action/test/action/test/action/test/action/id?quick-search-select=student
```

I wanted it to go to `http://localhost/alias/test/action` (my parameters are in post data).  It looks like it is appending the new "test/action" form action to the "id" part of the URL.  Notice how it goes away with each new submission.

The page is actually going to the right place, which is the default, because there is no test controller.  But it keeps putting that on the end of the URL.  If I put an existing URL

Why is it appending like that from the form tag?  Using IIS if it matters.

Comment: You are using a relative url in your `action`, the the actual path is prepended. You'd have to set a base path or use an absolute url like `/alias/test/action`

Comment: @jeroen thanks.  Think about putting that in an answer, so I can check it.

Comment: A bit poor, but if it helps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a relative url in your `action` attribute, so the actual path is prepended.

You'd have to set a base path or use an absolute url like `/alias/test/action`.

To add a base path, you can add this in the head of your html:

```
<base href="/alias/">
```